# Finding if a number is a perfect square through sum of odd numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I'm stuck in this Python exercise:

> A number *n* is a perfect square if, for some natural number *k*, it can be written as the sum of the first *k* odd numbers, that is, *1 + 3 +· · ·+k*. The first five perfect squares are 1, 4, 9, 16 and 25. Write a function perfect_square(n) whose result is True, if *n* is a perfect square. Otherwise, the result must be False.

This is the solution I came up with:

```
def perfect_square(n):
    s=0
    for i in range(1, n+1,2):
        s=s+i
    if s==n:
        print(True)
    else:
        print(False)
```

When I tested the numbers of the question, 1 and 4 were correct, but from 9 the result is "False" when it should be True. Can someone please help me find what is wrong with my code? This is for an introductory class, so this is supposed to have a simple solution.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you explain step by step how you intend your code to return True when it is given n=9?

Comment: You apparently assumed that `n'` always equals `k`. If so, what was your reason?

Comment: @PM77-1 k is obviously less than n, so even if range is wider than necessary and it could be used to check if sum up to that point matches the input...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - only if you are checking ***inside*** the loop.

Comment: @ArkitPatel I meant "s" and not "soma", forgot to change that in here sorry!

Comment: @mari00 probably the solution posted by Nathan will work if you are checking somewhere that `n` has an integer square root

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> for some natural number k

You're not given an exact `k` but we know the upper bound couldn't be bigger than `n` so just check them all.

```
def perfect_square(n):
    summation = 0
    for value in range(1, n + 1, 2):
        summation += value
        
        if summation == n:
            return True
        
    return False
```

Comment: This solved it, thank you! From what I'm understanding, my problem was basically the indentation of the return True/ False statements. Thank you for such a clean and straight forward answer!

Comment: You can stop evaluation much earlier. `n` is a valid upper bound, but I'd also add `elif summation > n: return False`, since the sum never decreases.